# Debuging x64 with VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to debug an application deployed on an x64 server, but I cant find the x64 remote debuging

this link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2022 only offers AMD64, ARM64 or x86

Am I missing something

Comment: don't you see AMD64?

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly didnt consider AMD64 ... as you were, I'll show myself out then ...